# Do we really need both of the tags glfw AND glfw3?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag for [glfw](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glfw) which has 40 questions and a description, and a tag for [glfw3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glfw3), which has 15 questions and no description.

Since the first question with `glfw3`, there seems to have been more questions tagged with `glfw` than with `glfw3`.

I'm not familiar enough with the library to argue that we *need*, or that we *don't need* the tag `glfw3`.

However, since there is not a lot of questions that are tagged with that and users seem to prefer `glfw`, so I would think that an expert browsing the questions wouldn't mind that much browsing 'only' questions with the tag `glfw`.

Should we keep the distinction or should we make `glfw3` a synonym of `glfw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should make `glfw3` a synonym of `glfw` because volume of questions is not big enough for it to matter.

Comment: Ditto, the differences aren't big enough for separate tags to provide a benefit for people, it's not the same kind of difference between direct3d 9 and 12.

Comment: I've merged and linked `glfw3` to `glfw`.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Thanks a lot!